# Read a file permission and apply to another in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script and I want to apply the permissions of a given file to another, given that the owner of both files is the same. The files can be huge, so moving the file contents using

```
cp dest tmp
rm dest
cp source dest
echo tmp > dest
rm tmp
```

is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your `chmod` support the `--reference` option? It does exactly what you need.

Comment: yup it supports reference. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE1="$HOME/.bashrc"
FILE2="$HOME/.profile"

FPERM=`stat -c "%a" "$FILE1"`
chmod $FPERM "$FILE2"
```

PS. If also ownership:

```
FUID=`stat -c "%U" "$FILE1"`
FGID=`stat -c "%G" "$FILE1"`

chown $FUID:$FGID "$FILE2"
```

Comment: really nice, it will be useful in other scenario too.